# Javascript strange result of the sum

Tags: javascript, sum

My application works fine, but sometimes it return "strange" result, I dont't understand why it happens. For ex:

```
var a = 80.78, b = 83.49, c = 45.33
alert (a+b+c); //209.59999999999997 instead of 209.60
```

Thanks
A.

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Another proof for poorly written tutorials or books. Not your fault OP. Just follow the links and ask a new question if you have trouble with understanding the reason or math behind it.

Comment: never heard about that...thanks